# Failed to install Varnish due to dependencies errors

Tags: varnish

I'm trying install varnish on CentOS 6.7 and get following errors. Can somebody help?

yum install varnish

.....

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: varnish-libs-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-libs-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: varnish-4.1.0-1.el7.x86_64 (varnish-4.1)
           Requires: systemd-sysv
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install varnish from source.  Follow these steps:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/installation/install.html#compiling-varnish-from-source

Start by downloading the tarball:

http://repo.varnish-cache.org/source/

Then install the packages listed:

```
yum install -y autoconf automake jemalloc-devel libedit-devel libtool ncurses-devel pcre-devel pkgconfig python-docutils python-sphinx graphviz

tar xzvf downloaded-filename.tar.gz
cd name-of-the-folder-from-tarball
sh autogen.sh
sh configure
make
make check
(go make some tea)
make install
```

Read the notes on starting the service: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/installation/install.html#compiling-varnish-from-source

Comment: And here is another alternative  https://thornelabs.net/2015/03/29/setup-varnish-4-on-centos-6-as-a-caching-server-and-load-balancer.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to comment but I've upvoted the answer above. I just used it to install Varnish 5.2 on Amazon Linux. The downside of this approach is that you don't get a nice tidy "sudo service varnish start" option, but the upside is that at least you've got Varnish 5.

One change to the answer above. The location of the source has changed. You'll find it here now:

http://varnish-cache.org/releases/